# Как сделать задержку в скрипте чтобы лимиты API Google Sheets не срабатывали?

Tags: php, google-spreadsheet

```
    <?php

$dir = __DIR__.'/scripts/'; //Путь до папки со всеми скриптами, относительно этого скрипта. Внутри не должно быть папок, только скрипты .php
$baseUrl = 'https://exemple.ru/scripts/'; //Внешний путь до папки со скриптами со / на конце

$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as $filename) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl . $filename);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 10); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_exec($curl);   
    curl_close($curl);  
}
```

Есть скрипт который запускает скрипты в папке. Это нужно для обновления данных в таблицах на сайте. Из-за лимитов гугла не все таблицы обрабатываются.

> This version of the Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user. Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately. There is no daily usage limit.

Как нибудь можно добавить задержку при переборе скриптов из папки? Пробовал изменять значение CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, но это не помогло

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php ?

Comment: Это нужно добавить в цикл?

Comment: да, в начале или в конце.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В самом простом варианте как-то так, если мы предполагаем, что обращение к Google API идет один раз за итерацию цикла. Если чаще, то замените `$req++` на `$req += N`

```
$req = 0;
foreach ($files as $filename) {
    if ($req == 500) {
      sleep(100);
      $req = 0;
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl . $filename);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 10); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_exec($curl);   
    curl_close($curl);
    $req++;
}
```

Comment: только написать лучше `sleep(1)` (если она не переопределена), т.к. время указывается в секундах, а не в милисекундах. Иначе можно получить время выполнения скрипта в *N x 100* секунд. Т.е. для выполнения, например, 2000 запросов будет 4 x 100 = 400 секунд (6 мин, 40 сек).